# how to change a vector to corresponding names without using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I have a vector `c(1,3,4,2,5,4,3,1,6,3,1,4,2)`, and I want make 1="a", 2="b", and so on

So my final outputs should look like `c(a,c,d,b...)`

I know that I can use for loop and if statement to do this, but is there any other quicker ways to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the built-in constant `letters`.

```
vec <- c(1,3,4,2,5,4,3,1,6,3,1,4,2)
res <- letters[vec]
res
#[1] "a" "c" "d" "b" "e" "d" "c" "a" "f" "c" "a" "d" "b"
```

To replace with any other values you can construct a vector to subset.

```
value <- c('apples', 'banana', 'grapes', .....)
res <- value[vec]
```

Comment: Sure. What if I want something other than letters, such as "apples", "cars"...? I just wonder is  there any method to change the values quickly

Comment: Yes, the logic remains the same. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `match`

```
letters[match(vec, unique(vec))]
```